# Iphone Web Wrapper Needed

Tags: iphone

I have a prebuild web app that I want to submit to the app store but I need a iphone we wrapper in order to submit it. can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Make an app with 1 view: [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Not true. Apple does not allow publishing of such apps. The must have some functionality.

Comment: This is a very old answer but it is a gray area. It depends on how well you obfuscate it... Facebook is essentially a web wrapper, as are many bank apps

Comment: You can use an http traffic sniffer to determine which urls are being requested from the Facebook app. If you inspect them manually, you will see how Facebook builds much of its interface from uiwebviews.